# Bootstrap class btn-arrow-left not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey fellas I need a left arrow btn like this

[image: bootstrap left arrow button]

I have added `btn-arrow-left` class but its not working. Any suggestions

```
<div id="leftButon" class="col-md-3">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-arrow-left">Default</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this--

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <style type="text/css">
            .btn { /* just for this demo. */
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.btn-arrow-right,
.btn-arrow-left {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
}
.btn-arrow-right {
    padding-left: 36px;
}
.btn-arrow-left {
    padding-right: 36px;
}
.btn-arrow-right:before,
.btn-arrow-right:after,
.btn-arrow-left:before,
.btn-arrow-left:after { /* make two squares (before and after), looking similar to the button */
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px; /* move it down because of rounded corners */
    width: 22px; /* same as height */
    height: 22px; /* button_outer_height / sqrt(2) */
    background: inherit; /* use parent background */
    border: inherit; /* use parent border */
    border-left-color: transparent; /* hide left border */
    border-bottom-color: transparent; /* hide bottom border */
    border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 0px; /* round arrow corner, the shorthand property doesn't accept "inherit" so it is set to 4px */
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
}
.btn-arrow-right:before,
.btn-arrow-right:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg); /* rotate right arrow squares 45 deg to point right */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.btn-arrow-left:before,
.btn-arrow-left:after {
    transform: rotate(225deg); /* rotate left arrow squares 225 deg to point left */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
}
.btn-arrow-right:before,
.btn-arrow-left:before { /* align the "before" square to the left */
    left: -11px;
}
.btn-arrow-right:after,
.btn-arrow-left:after { /* align the "after" square to the right */
    right: -11px;
}
.btn-arrow-right:after,
.btn-arrow-left:before { /* bring arrow pointers to front */
    z-index: 1;
}
.btn-arrow-right:before,
.btn-arrow-left:after { /* hide arrow tails background */
    background-color: white;
}
           </style>
           </head>
           <body>
           <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-arrow-left">Default</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-arrow-left">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-arrow-left">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-arrow-right">Info</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-arrow-right">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-arrow-right">Danger</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**code courtsey**

http://jsfiddle.net/shpoont/3cA4x/